# Faster iteration over 2D Numpy/CuPy arrays based on unique values

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cupy

I am currently looping over a numpy array to slice it and do some ndarray array. Just the time neeed is currently much to long, due to the sice of the array of 2001*2001 elements. Therefore I hope, that someone might surgest a hint, how to speedup the code:

```py
import cupy as cp
from time import time

height, width = 187, 746
org_sized = cp.random.rand(2001, 2001) * 60

height_mat = cp.random.rand(height, width) * 100 # orinally values getting larger from (0, width//2) to the outside with the distance squared

indices = cp.indices((height, width))
y_offsets = indices[0]
x_offsets = indices[1] - (width + 1)/2
angle_mat = cp.round_(2*(90 - cp.rad2deg(cp.arctan2(y_offsets, x_offsets))) + 180).astype(int)

weights = cp.random.rand(361)/ 10  # weights oroiginally larger in the middle

# pad the org_sized matrix with zeros to a fit a size of (2001+heigth, 2001+weight)
west = cp.zeros((org_sized.shape[0], width // 2))
east = cp.zeros((org_sized.shape[0], round(width // 2)))

enlarged_size = cp.hstack((west, org_sized))
enlarged_size = cp.hstack((enlarged_size, east))

south = cp.zeros((height, enlarged_size.shape[1]))

enlarged_size = cp.vstack((enlarged_size, south))

shadow_time_hrs = cp.zeros_like(org_sized)


for y in range(org_sized.shape[0]):
    start_time = time()
    for x in range(org_sized.shape[1]):
        # shift h_extras and angles that they match in size, and are correctly aligned
        short_elevations = enlarged_size[y:y+height, x:x+width]

        overshadowed = (short_elevations - org_sized[y, x]) > height_mat
        shadowed_angles = angle_mat * overshadowed
        shadowed_segments = cp.unique(shadowed_angles)
        angle_segments = shadowed_segments

        sum_hours = cp.sum(weights[angle_segments])
        shadow_time_hrs[y, x] = sum_hours
    if (y % 100) == 0:
        print(f"Computation for line {y} took: {time() - start_time}.")
```

Firstly I used numbas @njit on the function calc_shadow_point, but it turned out, that it was 2 times slower than without. Therefore I switched to the numpy arrays to cupy arrays. Which give an speed-up of about 50 %. Probapy because the arrays are so small.

Are there other ways than to iteratere for this kind of problem, or is there a way to iterate with multi-threading over the iterators?

**Edit**: I changed the code to a minimum example of the same runtime (1.1 s per line of org_sized). Somehow I have to increase the computation speed. Everything below 10 % of the current computation time would make the code usable.
Due to the remarks I changed to np.unique to cp.unique, but as remarked. It didn't result in large speed-up barely 6 %. I am currently using a GTX 1060. But when it would help could manage to use a 1660 Ti.

Comment: I suspect that deeply embedded `unique` is the bottleneck.  That  sorts its input and checks for duplicates.

Comment: "to the numpy arrays to cupy arrays" you mean *from* numpy arrays *to* cupy arrays? Note that implementing efficiently `np.unique` on GPU is very hard and so it should not be very efficient. What are the values of `width` and `height`? More importantly what are the values in `shadowed_angles`? Note that having a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should help us.

Comment: The Idea was: to have an larger array (called elevations), with the size of (1, 2001,20001). And use some "filters" over it. the filters habe the shape of (heigth, width) which is determine on startup and not fix. In my current example its (187, 746). But the ratio is fix (besides rounding). The current type of showded_angles is int32. But Because it holdes vales of 0 to 360 (all intergers) I also could set it to "uint16", but. I guess, that would not make thinks better? The matrix angles stores the information of angle segments.

Answer (score 3):

**`unique` is slow** (both on CPUs and GPUs) because it generally either use internally a hash-map or a sort. Moreover, as you said, the array are too small to be efficient on the GPU resulting in huge kernel overheads. Hopefully, you do not need it: you can use **`bincount`** (with `minlength=361` and a flatten array) because you know the values are **small positive integers** in the bounded range `0:361`. Actually, you do not actually need to *count* the values like `bincount` does, you just want to know which values of the range `0:361` exists in `shadowed_angles`. Thus, a faster implementation of `bincount` can be written using **Numba**. Moreover, the array **computations can be done in a row** reducing the amount of *allocations* and the *memory pressure*. Finally, **parallelism** can be used to speed up the computation (using `prange` and `parallel=True` of Numba).

Here is the resulting **CPU-based** implementation:

```py
@nb.njit
def computeSumHours(org_sized, enlarged_size, angle_mat, height_mat, shadow_time_hrs, y, x):
    height, width = height_mat.shape
    short_elevations = enlarged_size[y:y+height, x:x+width]
    shadowed_segments = np.zeros(361)

    for y2 in range(height):
        for x2 in range(width):
            overshadowed = (short_elevations[y2, x2] - org_sized[y, x]) > height_mat[y2, x2]
            shadowed_angle = angle_mat[y2, x2] * overshadowed
            shadowed_segments[shadowed_angle] = weights[shadowed_angle]

    return shadowed_segments.sum()

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def computeLine(org_sized, enlarged_size, angle_mat, height_mat, shadow_time_hrs, y):
    height, width = height_mat.shape

    for x in nb.prange(org_sized.shape[1]):
        shadow_time_hrs[y, x] = computeSumHours(org_sized, enlarged_size, angle_mat, height_mat, shadow_time_hrs, y, x)

def computeAllLines(org_sized, enlarged_size, angle_mat, height_mat, shadow_time_hrs):
    height, width = height_mat.shape

    for y in range(org_sized.shape[0]):
        start_time = time()
        computeLine(org_sized, enlarged_size, angle_mat, height_mat, shadow_time_hrs, y)
        if (y % 100) == 0:
            print("Computation for line %d took: %f." % (y, time() - start_time))

computeAllLines(org_sized, enlarged_size, angle_mat, height_mat, shadow_time_hrs)
```

Here are the timing results per iteration on my machine (using a i7-9600K and a GTX-1660-Super):

```
Reference implementation (CPU): 2.015 s
Reference implementation (GPU): 0.882 s
Optimized implementation (CPU): 0.082 s
```

This is **10 times** faster than the reference GPU-based implementation and **25 times** faster than the reference CPU-based one.

Note that the same technique can be used on GPU, but not using CuPy: one need to write a GPU kernel doing that (e.g. using CUDA). However, this is quite complex to do that efficiently.

Comment: Thanks alot. It's also 10 times faster on my maschine and 50 times faster than my own try of using numba! Fantastic.

Comment: @OrdensRitter You are welcome. Do not forget to validate the answer ;) .